# ignore last value in a table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

```
  <p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="data">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr>
        <th class="ui-column-title thdesign" *ngFor="let col of columns" >
          {{col.header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns">
      <tr *ngIf="data?.decisionTypeStatus != 1">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <div *ngIf="!col.isAnchor" class="colDesign">{{data[col.field]}}</div>
            <div *ngIf="col.isAnchor">
              <a class="anchor" href="{{templateUrl}}?{{splitCoimPath(data.coimId)}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                {{data[col.field]}}
              </a>
            </div>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
```

ts:

```
cols = [
    { field: 'docVersionNumber', header: 'גרסה', isAnchor: false},
    { field: 'uploadBy', header: 'משתמש', isAnchor: false},
    { field: 'uploadOn', header: 'מועד העלאה', isAnchor: false,},
    { field: 'fileName', header: 'מסמך', isAnchor: true},
    { field: 'decisionType', header: 'החלטה', isAnchor: false},
    { field: 'decisionReasons', header: 'הערות', isAnchor: false},

  ];
  @Input() data: VersionDetailsModel[];
```

[image: the table]
Hi
I need the last value in the data will not show.. from some reason data.length not working from the html also id data.length > 0
Thanks

Comment: please post complete code,  not just fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the wrong condition.
Try this condition, Compare the last length of array with index. it will not show the last value.

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data let-columns="columns ">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="!col.isAnchor && (i != (columns.length - 1))" class="colDesign">{{data[col.field]}}</div>
      <div *ngIf="col.isAnchor && (i != (columns.length - 1))">
        <a class="anchor" href="{{templateUrl}}?{{splitCoimPath(data.coimId)}}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          {{data[col.field]}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: how  would you verify i value

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I had written l by mistake instead of i .
We will verify the index in *ngFor loop in this way 
let i = index

Comment: thanks but I meant the rows not the columns

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your table if you can

Comment: do you have an answer for me?

Comment: What's the problem with data.length ?

I think data.length will not work with 1 record.
so change the condition (i != (columns.length - 1)) with (columns.length > 1 && (i != (columns.length - 1)))

It will hide last row (last record of your array) in your table

Comment: columns.length are about the columns not the data. I wont to hide the last line(row). columns are like field,header of the table - you caan see in the typescript